# Why does my MapThread expression fail in this case?

Tags: list-manipulation, warning-messages

This morning, I opened one of my previous notebooks and evaluated it. Surprisingly, the code produced an error.

This took me a whole four hours to find the problem and it is with `MapThread`.

I give a simplified version here

```
MapThread[f, {{{a, b}, {c, d, x}}, {{u, v}, {s, t, y}}}, 2]
```

This code produces an error in *Mathematica* 10.2

> MapThread::mptd: Object {{a, b}, {c, d, x}} at position {2, 1} in MapThread[f, {{{a, b}, {c, d, x}}, {{u, v}, {s, t, y}}}, 2] has only 1 of required 2 dimensions. >>

It should output this result

```
{{f[a, u], f[b, v]}, {f[c, s], f[d, t], f[x, y]}}
```

But it is not. I am pretty sure, there is no such problem in the previous version. And I can't understand why this code can't work in 10.2.

**Edit**
According to tests carried out by several users, it seems that this kind of `MapThread` all get the same error. Maybe I had a wrong recall. But it is still an interesting question why this kind of threading(looks quite natural) is not supported.

Comment: In the "Possible issues" my MapThread doc says `All arguments must be lists of the same length`

Comment: belisarius is right in  way, it would be good to know what output you expect. However that's not the usual error message for that scenario (`incompatible dimensions`), so I'm not sure it's the only issue.

Comment: Perhaps you should write  `Apply[f, {{{a, b}, {c, d, x}}, {{u, v}, {s, t, y}}}, {2}]` which gives `{{f[a, b], f[c, d, x]}, {f[u, v], f[s, t, y]}}`

Comment: @belisariusisforth I think your example is another issue that should be differentiate from my example. `MapThread[f, {{a, b, c}, t, {u, v, w}}]` is wrong because `MapThread` can't not thread through the second argument. But `MapThread[f, {{{a, b}, {c, d, x}}, {{u, v}, {s, t, y}}}, 2]` is done on the 2nd level, at 2nd level there is no such problem.

Comment: @Pickett I add a comment

Comment: What version of Mathematica was your old notebook?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch probably v9

Comment: @m_goldberg No, not this one. I edit my post, I want threaded result

Comment: v9 also gives the same error

Comment: @QuantumDot Thank you for testing. Now I have no idea :(   It is a pitty that this threading didn't work now, no matter that it may work in some older  version according to my memory.

Comment: @QuantumDot v8.0.4 also gives the same error.

Comment: OK, then `MapThread[f, #] & /@ Transpose[{{{a, b}, {c, d, x}}, {{u, v}, {s, t, y}}}]`

Comment: @m_goldberg Thank you for your answer. By the way, do you know why `MapThread` doesn't support this kind of threading? I think it is so natural to thread.

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be a number of ways to achieve what you want. I don't have MMA 10.2 at hand right now, but the same error comes up in 10.1. The primitive way is to improve `MapThread` like so:

```
mapThread[f_, args_List, depth_Integer:1] :=
MapThread[f, PadRight[args, ConstantArray[Automatic, depth+1], $ToNothing], depth] /. f[$ToNothing..] :> Nothing
```

`Nothing` was introduced in 10.2, so in 10.1 I would use some vanishing function instead, like `Unevaluated[Sequence[]]`.

This is a general fix, that allows for proper function even if the elements at level 2 of the arguments are lists themselves.

You can also just make `f` `Listable`:

```
SetAttributes[f, Listable];
f[{{a, b}, {c, d, x}}, {{u, v}, {s, t, y}}]
{{f[a, u], f[b, v]}, {f[c, s], f[d, t], f[x, y]}}
```

Repeated application of `Thread` works too:

```
Thread /@ Thread@f[{{a, b}, {c, d, x}}, {{u, v}, {s, t, y}}]
```

**Modifying built-in functions can lead to problems! Don't do the following unless you know what you're doing!**

If you have some code where there's a lot of threading over ragged arrays, you can overload `MapThread` directly, instead of creating auxiliary functions and modifying the code. This is the same fix, as at the top of my answer, but applied directly to the built-in `MapThread`. It includes a conditional, which checks, if it is at all necessary to apply the modified definition.

```
Unprotect[MapThread];
MapThread[f_, args_List, depth_Integer: 1] /; ArrayDepth[args] <= depth :=
 MapThread[f, 
   PadRight[args, ConstantArray[Automatic, depth + 1], $ToNothing], depth] /.
       f[$ToNothing ..] :> Unevaluated[Sequence[]]
```

**EDIT**
Oh yeah, you might run into a problem if the sublists in the second argument of `MapThread` are of different shapes.

For example:

```
mapThread[f, {{{a}, {c, d, x}}, {{u, v}, {s, t, y}}}, 2]
{{f[a, u], f[$ToNothing, v]}, {f[c, s], f[d, t], f[x, y]}}
```

I'm struggling to think of a consistent way to remedy this problem.